# Is looping over an enumeration a single responsibility?

Tags: c#, oop, single-responsibility-principle

Is looping over a collection a single responsibility and do I have to implement it in its own class?

This is a concrete example for the general question: I have a class, with a method, that loops over a enumeration and deals with each item:

```
internal class StorageRestorer
{
    #region log4net

    private static log4net.ILog _log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(StorageRestorer<TEntity>));

    #endregion log4net

    private ServiceController _serviceController;

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new instance of the StorageRestorer class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="serviceController">Service controller, where to resore the storage.</param>
    public StorageRestorer(ServiceController serviceController)
    {
        _serviceController = serviceController;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Restores the given storage items into the service controller.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="items">Storage items to be restored.</param>
    public void Restore(IEnumerable<StorageItem> items)
    {
        foreach (var item in items)
            Restore(item);
    }

    private void Restore(StorageItem item)
    {
        if (item.Status == EntityStates.Added)
        {
            _serviceController.AddObject(item.Entity);
            return;
        }

        _serviceController.AttachObject(item.Entity);
        switch (item.Status)
        {
            case EntityStates.Deleted:
                _serviceController.DeleteObject(item.Entity);
                break;
            case EntityStates.Modified:
                _serviceController.UpdateObject(item.Entity);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

My question is now: does this class violate the single responsibility principle because of the loop?

Comment: What is the name of class? Is it the all code?

Comment: I added the code of the whole class. The class is responsible for restoring the items back to the service controller.

Comment: you should put it in its own class, because the action to be performed is specific for each instance of that class, but this question should be asked in code review site.

Comment: Why is the action called "restore" You are updating or deleting entities. Btw, i would change the constructor and the field to a `IServiceController`-interface which makes the classes less coupled.

Comment: @Tim: because it restores some previously generated state by adding and deleting objects. The ServiceController is an interface but not named with an leading `I`(I have read Clean Code of Robert C. Martin).

Comment: @scher: but isn't that just a side effect of committing the changes to the storages(f.e. a database)? If i'd use a restorer i'd not expect my objects to be deleted.

Comment: @Tim: Maybe `StorageItem` is not the right name. The `StorageItem `contains information of an object at a specific time in a WCF cache. At this time, e.g. the object has been marked as deleted. After a crash of the system, the status of the object has to be restored. Therefore the object has to be marked again as delete, what is done via the `DeleteObject(...)` method of the ServiceController.

Comment: I am more interested in the general question, that should have been made clearer by the concrete example.

Comment: Funny thing, I asked a similar question regarding programming style and it got closed because it was 'primarily opinion based' (just as I see this one). Maybe the moderators should learn a bit or two.

Comment: As for the content of the question itself, my `opinion` is that it does not violate SRP in any way. However, nitpicking a bit, why not enlarge the switch to include the `Added` case?

Comment: Iteration is a flow control statement and as such a language primitive. A class combines data and behavior.  At some point as you move closer to the processor core, classes lose their meaning and are not helpful anymore. Likewise it would not help to have a class for assignments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that you do not want your code to be peer reviewed, so I will stick to the questions. I do not think that your class violates the SRP. Your class is a "storage restorer", and that is just what the class does. In fact, the actual operations (add, attach, delete and upate) are implemented in another class that complies with the responsibility to carrying out the atomic operations. The code is easy to read and very understandable, so no problem there. Maybe some could argue that the code could be changed to:

```
public void Restore(IEnumerable<StorageItem> items)
{
    foreach (var item in items)
        item.Restore(_serviceController);
}
```

and send the responsibility of the individual item restoration to the storage item itself, but I think the class is OK as is.

About the general question, a loop is just a mean to achieve what you want to accomplish, but not a responsibility itself. Sometimes in order to achieve what the responsibility requires, you will need to write several loops, if conditions, nested switches, and that does not mean that you will need to write a class for every structure you write. Maybe it will be a good idea to write private functions that help read the code, as long as the private functions help you achieve what the class really need to do, and nothing else (accomplish with the responsibility it has).

Comment: That's a bit of purism (delegating the restoration logic to the `StorageItem` class). This class would become just a `foreach` helper IMHO..

Answer (score 0):

The only responsibility of your class is to dispatch entity by it's `Status`. So, no violations. Even more, your class looks like truncated version of `Repository` pattern. But I guess this is beyond your question.

The only thing I would note is to make

```
void Restore(StorageItem item) // [1]
```

method `public`. You will extend `StorageRestorer`'s interface without any violations. Method

```
void Restore(IEnumerable<StorageItem> items) // [2]
```

is nothing but a minor helper. In your case, method `[2]` can be easily throw away. There is no any reason to make method `[1]` be `private`. If you do not use it now, it doesn't mean you will not use it later. If you can do some actions with elements inside collection, *not a collection itself*, it is expected that you would be able to do these actions with a single element.

Otherwise, something like this could appear later:

```
resporer.Restore(new [] { item }); // OMG, who wrote that API? o.O
```

Moreover, not in your particular case, such helpers can apply some internal optimizations. For example, this is what `List<T>.AddRange` actually does.

So, back to your questing. There is no any actual violation, but it is also not the best design choice. It *could be* reasonable to have methods like `[2]`. Mostly depends on your whole code base. If you never ever operate on a single element, only on enumerations, this trade off will fits your needs.

Comment: "If you do not use it now, it doesn't mean you will not use it later." -- so the argument for keeping it private is "you do not use it now" - you can always make it public later if it turns out you need it. If you make it public now, it becomes part of your public interface, which means that if you want to change it later (because it turns out you need something _like_ it which is slightly different) you have a breaking change. Adding public methods is easy, changing them is hard.

Comment: @CompuChip It could be a library used by other people, who do not have ability to switch it to public. What is really important is that class operates not on collection itself, but on collection's elements. So having only `[2]` method without `[1]` at least could confuse other people. In this particular case method `[1]` it a primary method, method `[2]` is some kind of syntax sugar.

Comment: @CompuChip "you can always make it public later" - are you work alone? It is not a good argument when you work in team. Even if people have access to source code, unlikely they will make any changes. Most likely it is a tested piece of code that none would be happy to change, spend time to figure out if it safe to refactor, take responsibility if you have no auto tests and so on. From my experience most people will find most easiest way: "I can wrap it into array and everything will be fine".

Comment: I go with @CompuChip: Make it public when you need it, not in advance